# Mensaje de confirmación con sweet alert 2, y guardar un elemento al confirmar con Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, sweetalert2

Buenas quiero implementar mensajes de confirmación con Sweet Alert 2. La idea es que pregunte si el usuario esta seguro de guardar los datos.

Para el guardado recibo por POSTS los datos en el controlador

```
 public function confirmarSolicitud(Request $request)
 {
   $id_empleado            = $request->id_empleado; 
   $cantidad_solicitada    = $request->cantidad_solicitada; //Es un array
   $id_dotacion            = $request->dotacion_id;  //Es un array 
  }
```

la ruta empleada es:

```
Route::post('confirmar_solicitud','Endowment\SolicitudesController@confirmarSolicitud')->name('confirmar_solicitud');
```

y la vista:

```
<form action="{{ route ('confirmar_solicitud')}}" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field()}}

<input type="text" name="id_empleado" value="{{ $id_empleado}}">

<table border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%">

 <thead align="center">
 <tr>                               
<th width="50%"><b>Nombre de la Dotación </b></th>                             
<th width="20%"><b>Cantidad a Solicitar</b></th>
</tr>
</thead>

@foreach ($especificaciones as $ver)
<tbody>
<tr>

<td>
<input type="text" name="dotacion_id[]" value="{{ $ver->id}}">
</td>
<td>
 {{$ver->name}}

</td>
  <td>
 <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cantidad_solicitada" name="cantidad_solicitada[]" value="1">
</td> 

</tr>
</tbody>
 @endforeach
</table>

 <button type="submit" id="boton" class="btn btn-info" style="width: 200px">Crear Solicitud</button>
</form>
```

Se supone que al pulsar el botón aparezca el mensaje de confirmación y que al pulsar confirmar se realice el guardado de los datos. Estuve investigando y debo enviar los datos del formulario por ajax al controlador y luego recibirlos para hacer el guardado. Pero no estoy clara de como hacerlo, he leído pero no he resuelto mucho, si alguien puede ayudarme.

esta seria el javascript a implementar. Falta definir el envió de los datos por ajax.

```
    $("#boton").onclick(function(event){
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Esta seguro?',
  text: "luego no puede modificar los datos!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Si, deseo guardar.'

}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {

         $.ajax({
             url:urls,
            type:'POST',
            data:dato,
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
          }

      });  
  }
})
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con este código

```
$("#boton").onclick(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let form = event.target;

        swal.fire({
            title: '¿Seguro que desea eliminar el registro?',
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
            confirmButtonText: '¡Si, eliminar!'
        }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Es básicamente el mismo código que tienes, con la diferencia que se agrega el `event.preventDefault` para evitar el comportamiento normal de un submit, y al final en la seccion del if del Sweetaler2 se hace un submit al form.

De esta forma no hay necesidad de hacerlo por ajax, pero en caso de que así lo requieras, cambias `form.submit()` y colocas tu código ajax.

Comment: Hola, estoy probando con el código que me indicas y al darle click al boton para continuar me arroja el siguiente error:
484 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: form.submit is not a function

Comment: listo! resolví así: document.getElementById("form").submit();